# How to get a bit value on particular position starting from msb?

Tags: java, bit

I never worked with bits in Java before, so the question is the following:
I have

```
byte a=254;
```

How to get a bits from this byte, starting from msb position?

```
If position == 0 it returns 1
If position == 7 it returns 0
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int getBitFromMSB(byte x,int position){
    return (x >>> (7 - position)) & 1;
}
```